# Trusted login provider is not sending configured input identity claim type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

I'm integrating Custom Java-IDP with SharePoint2016 using Claims Based Authentication (using WSFed11). ClaimTypeInformation shows following info.

```
PS C:\Users\windows> $ap.ClaimTypeInformation

    DisplayName                    : EmailAddress
    InputClaimType                 : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
    MappedClaimType                : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
    IsIdentityClaim                : True
    AcceptOnlyKnownClaimValues     : False
    ClaimValueModificationAction   : None
    ClaimValueModificationArgument :
    KnownClaimValues               : {}
    UpgradedPersistedProperties    : {}
```

On receiving the SAML token, the SharePoint produces following errors/ exceptions:

```
Trusted login provider 'Cool_IDP' is not sending configured input identity claim type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'.

STS Call: Failed to issue new security token. Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenService.SPRequestInfo.ValidateTrustedLoginRequest(SPRequestSecurityToken request)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenService.SPRequestInfo.InitializeForFederationAuthType(SPRequestSecurityToken request)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenService.GetTokenLifetime(Lifetime requestLifetime)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenService.Issue(IClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenService.Issue(IClaimsPrincipal principal, RequestSecurityToken request)

SPSecurityContext: Request for security token failed with exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm.    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message response)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties)

An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm..

Claims Saml Sign-In: Received saml is invalid. Could not find identity claim. Failed to get local token. Redirecting to error page.

SPFederationAuthenticationModule.GetReturnUrlFromResponse: Return url 'http://sharepointer/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=/' has same prefix as current context url 'http://sharepointer/_trust'.

Claims Saml Sign-In: Redirecting to error page '/_login/default.aspx?errorCode=TrustedMissingIdentityClaimSource=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepointer%2F%5Flayouts%2F15%2FAuthenticate%2Easpx%3FSource%3D%252F'.
```

Indeed, IDP sends the SAML token with same AttributeNamespace as that of configured via $emailClaimMap. But still it says, Trusted login provider 'Cool_IDP' is not sending configured input identity claim type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'.

See below snippet.

```
...
<saml:AttributeStatement>
    <saml:Subject>
        <saml:NameIdentifier+Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">elwoodf1@coolidp.com</saml:NameIdentifier>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
        </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Attribute+AttributeName="EmailAddress"+AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
        <saml:AttributeValue>elwoodf1@coolidp.com</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
...
```

Please refer the complete SAML token message below.

```
<wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    <wst:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</wst:TokenType>
    <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <saml:Assertion+AssertionID="id-ZJf89YVouG9kacNvzvI4g2aPCXY-"+IssueInstant="2018-03-20T20:41:10Z"+Issuer="https://coolidp.com/cool"+MajorVersion="1"+MinorVersion="1">
            <saml:Conditions+NotBefore="2018-03-20T20:40:40Z"+NotOnOrAfter="2018-03-20T20:46:40Z">
                <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                    <saml:Audience>urn:sharepoint:SP80Portal</saml:Audience>
                </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
            </saml:Conditions>
            <saml:AuthenticationStatement+AuthenticationInstant="2018-03-20T20:41:10Z"+AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password">
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:NameIdentifier+Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">elwoodf1@coolidp.com</saml:NameIdentifier>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
            </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
            <saml:AttributeStatement>
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:NameIdentifier+Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">elwoodf1@coolidp.com</saml:NameIdentifier>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
                <saml:Attribute+AttributeName="EmailAddress"+AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                    <saml:AttributeValue>elwoodf1@coolidp.com</saml:AttributeValue>
                </saml:Attribute>
            </saml:AttributeStatement>
            <dsig:Signature>
                <dsig:SignedInfo>
                    <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod+Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <dsig:SignatureMethod+Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <dsig:Reference+URI="#id-ZJf89YVouG9kacNvzvI4g2aPCXY-">
                        <dsig:Transforms>
                            <dsig:Transform+Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <dsig:Transform+Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </dsig:Transforms>
                        <dsig:DigestMethod+Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <dsig:DigestValue>pl+rlwstQI7j2H2ntcaaPIzSk7JPCebqReyQz6/vUuYQ=</dsig:DigestValue>
                    </dsig:Reference>
                </dsig:SignedInfo>
                <dsig:SignatureValue>J2inQbWWU9gNwY..........</dsig:SignatureValue>
                <dsig:KeyInfo>
                    <dsig:X509Data>
                        <dsig:X509Certificate>MIIDYDCCAkig..........</dsig:X509Certificate>
                    </dsig:X509Data>
                </dsig:KeyInfo>
            </dsig:Signature>
        </saml:Assertion>
    </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
    <policy:AppliesTo>
        <wa:EndpointReference>
            <wa:Address>urn:sharepoint:SP80Portal</wa:Address>
        </wa:EndpointReference>
    </policy:AppliesTo>
    <wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier+ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">id-ZJf89YVouG9kacNvzvI4g2aPCXY-</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
    <wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier+ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">id-ZJf89YVouG9kacNvzvI4g2aPCXY-</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
    <wst:Lifetime>
        <Created>2018-03-20T20:40:40Z</Created>
        <Expires>2018-03-20T20:46:40Z</Expires>
    </wst:Lifetime>
</wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues found during this exercise:

1. Time difference between 'NotBefore and NotOnOrAfter in 'Conditions' statement of SAML Assertion must be >=10 minutes interval. SharePoint expects more time validity of SAML Assertion.
2. Custom IDP must send AttributeNamespace as "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims" and NOT "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress". See below RSTR snippet.

> ```
> <saml:AttributeStatement>
>     <saml:Subject>
>         <saml:NameIdentifier+Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">elwoodf1@cool.com</saml:NameIdentifier>
>         <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
>             <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
>         </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
>     </saml:Subject>
>     <saml:Attribute+AttributeName="emailaddress"+AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
>         <saml:AttributeValue>elwoodf1@cool.com</saml:AttributeValue>
>     </saml:Attribute>
> </saml:AttributeStatement>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the “urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer” to “urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer”.

Check the example for the SAML 2.0 below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_saml_assertion_examples.htm